# How do I crop a 2-d surface plot in MATLAB, to remove axes and white margins?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have written a program to process and print a 81x81 2D surface plot, which needs to be used as an input. Saving the plot made by Matlab includes side axes as well as white margins on the sides.
How do I crop this image to get just the (81pixels)x(81pixels) output as an image?

Answer (score 2):

Try placing this after your figure code, it will remove the margins around your figure.

```
set(gca,'units','pixels') % set the axes units to pixels
xx = get(gca,'position'); % get the position of the axes;
set(gcf,'units','pixels') % set the figure units to pixels
yy = get(gcf,'position'); % get the figure position;
set(gcf,'position',[yy(1) yy(2) xx(3) xx(4)]) % set the position of the figure to the length and width of the axes
set(gca,'units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]) % set the axes units to pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using surf plot and just save your array as image. So, you have 81x81 array. I'll use this one for the example:

```
 a = magic(81);
```

Now you need to normalize image in order to have values from 0 to 255:

```
 a = (a - min(min(a)))/(max(max(a))-min(min(a)))*255;
```

Finally you use `imwrite` to save your array as image.

```
 imwrite(a,jet(256),'SO_4.png')
```

The first argument is your 81x81 array. The second argument is colormap. You can specify any colormap you want, but I like the heatmap `jet(256)`. You can skip this argument, in this case the image would be grayscale. From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) you can find what colormaps are available and what they look like. The last argument is image name. The result is shown below:

[image]

Hope that helps, good luck.